FastApi - receive list of objects in body request from form
I have form from kinda div>inputs
every div have inputs type and text and every div represents a message (so it has type and text too). And I need to get in controller in FastAPI list of objects like
[
  {
    "type": "lorem",
    "text": "lorem",
  },
  ...
]

I tried multiple namings like message[0][type], message.0.type, etc.
Nothing worked for me.

How are you submitting you submitting your data to this endpoint? If you're going to have a complex structure with a list of objects with certain fields, using a Pydantic model as shown in the answer below is the way to go.

If  you're using a form with multiple input type=.. name="type" entries, you're going to have to have to parameters - type: List[str] = Form(), text: List[str] = Form() - and you'll then have to validate that these two have the same length. You can then use zip to get pairs of elements from each list.

In FastAPI, you can use Pydantic models to define the structure of your request body.
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Message(BaseModel):
    type: str
    text: str

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/messages/")
async def create_messages(messages: List[Message]):
    # Your logic here
    return {"messages": messages}

